# jquery datatables - refresh doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an htnl table I build with jquery dataTables. The code I use for that is:

```
var oTable = jQuery('#webcam-table').dataTable({
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   "bStateSave": true,
   "aaSorting": [[1,"desc"]],
   "aoColumnDefs": [
     { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4 ] }
   ]
});
```

This table also has a form with a checkbox on each row where a user can select one or more and hit a delete button. This uses jquery `ajax`:

```
jQuery(".deletebutton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //cancel click event on start
    var testchecked = jQuery(':checkbox:checked').length;
    if (testchecked == 0) {
        alert('Please select at least one video');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected videos?"))
        {
            var checked = jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get();
            var $this = jQuery(this);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw',
                data: {checkedarray:checked},
                success: function(data){
                    jQuery('#deleteform input:checkbox').each(function(){
                        if(this.checked){
                            jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What this does is remove a row in the table. This is where I have a problem with dataTable as it has pages and when I delete one or more it doesn't refresh the table.

So I thought I should be able to add `fnDraw` to the code:

```
jQuery('#deleteform input:checkbox').each(function(){
       if(this.checked){
            jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
        }
oTable.fnDraw();
```

I thought this would refresh the table after my AJAX delete and after I've removed the row. But this doesn't even remove the row anymore nor does it update the table accordingly. Of course when I refresh the page manually everything is fine. Any ideas on how I can remove the rows selected and then refresh the dataTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DataTable API](http://datatables.net/api#fnDeleteRow) has a delete row function.

fnDeleteRow
Remove a row for the table

**Input parameters:**

- {mixed}: The index of the row from aoData to be deleted, or the TR
  element you want to delete
- {function|null}: Callback function
- {bool} [default=true]: Redraw the table or not

**Return parameter:**
{array}: The row that was deleted

**Code example:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Immediately remove the first row
  oTable.fnDeleteRow( 0 );
} );
```

Comment: Hrm, looks like the best option. I guess I have to loop through and delete all that have been selected. Not to mention adding some sort of index.